# Tracing only error traces in jaeger, finding out only the error traces in jaeger

Tags: jaeger

I actually was trying to sample only the error traces in my application but i already have a probabilistic sampler parameter set in my application which samples the span at the beginning itself and the rest span follow the same pattern after then, i tried using force sampling option in jaeger but it doesnt seem to override the original decision made by the initial span of getting sampled or not. Kindly help me out here.

Answer (score 7):

Jaeger clients implement so-called **head-based sampling**, where a sampling decision is made at the root of the call tree and propagated down the tree along with the trace context. This is done to guarantee consistent sampling of all spans of a given trace (or none of them), because we don't want to make the coin flip at every node and end up with partial/broken traces. Implementing on-error sampling in the head-based sampling system is not really possible. Imaging that your service is calling service A, which returns successfully, and then service B, which returns an error. Let's assume the root of the trace was not sampled (because otherwise you'd catch the error normally). That means by the time you know of an error from B, the whole sub-tree at A has been already executed and all spans discarded because of the earlier decision not to sample. The sub-tree at B has also finished executing. The only thing you can sample at this point is the spans in the current service. You could also implement a reverse propagation of the sampling decision via response to your caller. So in the best case you could end up with a sub-branch of the whole trace sampled, and possible future branches if the trace continues from above (e.g. via retries). But you can never capture the full trace, and sometimes the reason B failed was because A (successfully) returned some data that caused the error later.

Note that reverse propagation is not supported by the OpenTracing or OpenTelemetry today, but it has been discussed in the last meetings of the W3C Trace Context working group.

The alternative way to implement sampling is with **tail-based sampling**, a technique employed by some of the commercial vendors today, such as Lightstep, DataDog. It is also on the roadmap for Jaeger (we're working on it right now at Uber). With tail-based sampling 100% of spans are captured from the application, but only stored in memory in a collection tier, until the full trace is gathered and a sampling decision is made. The decision making code has a lot more information now, including errors, unusual latencies, etc. If we decide to sample the trace, only then it goes to disk storage, otherwise we evict it from memory, so that we only need to keep spans in memory for a few seconds on average. Tail-based sampling imposes heavier performance penalty on the traced applications because 100% of traffic needs to be profiled by tracing instrumentation.

You can read more about head-based and tail-based sampling either in Chapter 3 of my book (https://www.shkuro.com/books/2019-mastering-distributed-tracing/) or in the awesome paper *"So, you want to trace your distributed system? Key design insights from years of practical experience"* by Raja R. Sambasivan, Rodrigo Fonseca, Ilari Shafer, Gregory R. Ganger (http://www.pdl.cmu.edu/PDL-FTP/SelfStar/CMU-PDL-14-102.pdf).